# Given an ellipse and two points inside it (other than its foci) construct another ellipse tangent to the given one, using the 2 points as foci.

Tags: conic-sections

I´m interested in solving this problem, preferably by a synthetic method (including conics):

> Given an ellipse and two points inside it (other than its foci) construct another ellipse tangent to the given one, using the two points as foci.

I believe there can exist up to four different ellipses to fulfill the condition.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you hit your difficulties?  What don't you understand?  Have you tried simpler problems (e.g., ellipse and circle)?

Comment: Pick the new foci along the minor axis. Your new ellipse will touch the other one internally at the minor vertices.

Comment: @allawonder The foci are already given.

Comment: @user I said take the other two points along the minor axis.

Comment: Perhaps I didnt express propperly. The focii of the new ellipse (b) are the 2 points given inside the given ellipse (a). We must find one point in «a» which should be common to the tangents traced through it to «a» and «b».

Comment: Mr. Stock, I really did. In the case of a given circle, there is an equilateral hyperbola centered at the inverse points of the 2 given points which cuts the circle in up to 4 points, solutions to the problem. I've tried to translate the same system to a given ellipse, but no success.

Comment: I meant that the hyperbola is centered at the midpoint of the inverses.